# meaning of 'a theory of political human nature'

Tags: phrase-meaning, adjectives, adjective-phrases, attributive-nouns

Which one is the meaning of 'a theory of political human nature'?

1. a theory of the political nature of humans
2. a theory of the nature of political humans

I myself guess the first one is meant.

The phrase in context, from *Political Ideals* (1917) by Bertrand Russell:

> It may be said that the power of officials is much less dangerous than the power of capitalists, because officials have no economic interests that are opposed to those of wage-earners. But this argument involves far too simple **a theory of political human nature**—a theory which orthodox socialism adopted from the classical political economy,...

Comment: I suppose we can all agree on a fairly specific definition for ***human*** for your context, but there's no such precision with the word ***politics*** (we can talk about the politics of a family or an office, as well as "nation state" level politics). So the meaning of your example depends on the *exact* context in which it's used - effectively, "a matter of opinion" for people who might try to answer this question here.

Comment: Consider the situation if you replaced ***political*** with, say, ***competitive***. Suppose I tell you that I've developed a "theory of competitive human nature". You might assume my theory is based on the premise that only *some* people are competitive (and those are the only people my theory is concerned with), but I think that would be a rather perverse reading.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Thanks. I added the context. So according to your comment, grammar rules, alone, allow more than one interpretation for 'a theory of political human nature', and to understand what the author meant we must consider the context.

Comment: Now you've added more context, I see there's also reference to *the classical political economy* - which also involves two consecutive adjectives modifying a noun.As it happens, there are hundreds of written instances of the sequence *of human political nature* as well as *of political human nature*, but I expect few if any of them would reflect any difference in *meaning* based purely on the position of the word *political*. This despite the fact that *human nature* is a well-established collocation that you might not expect to be "broken" by an intervening adjective.

Comment: ...on the other hand, the second such example from your source *([classical political economy](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22classical+political+economy%22))* returns tens of thousands of written instances in Google Books, but there are effectively *no* written instances of the sequence *political classical economy*. In practice though, *political human nature* and *human political nature* would both simply mean *human nature considered from a political perspective*, and hardly anyone would even *consider* the possible semantic distinctions you've put forward.

Comment: The phrase is from a published book by an English author, and this question is not a 'request for proofreading', it's about meaning and grammar.

Comment: My original closevote was for "lack of detail" (i.e. - lack of *context*, which you've now added), so I will reverse my position and vote to reopen. It's still something of an "opinion-based" question, but in practice I think you'd have to accept that in your cited context it wouldn't really make much difference whether Russell was thinking in terms of the "political nature" of *(all)* humanity collectively, or the "human nature" of *(some)* politically-inclined people.But there's a general principle ***by default**, an adjective modifies the immediately following term*, which may be relevant.

Comment: It's interesting that some degree of ambiguity exists here even for native English speakers, @FumbleFingers. Thanks.

Comment: As I've tried to indicate, in practice I don't think your interpretation #2 is particularly *useful*. It's thus not particularly *likely* to be the nuance intended by the writer - so if he *had* specifically wanted to make such an unusual distinction, he'd probably have chosen a more long-winded way of expressing himself. But that's more a matter of opinion than of English syntax. But to repeat myself, *by default* you should assume that ***human nature*** (as a well-established collocation) is being modified "in toto" by the additional clarifying / restricting term ***political***.